# Error 1004 when insert multiple strings in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

The code :

```
Sub ConcatenateS()
    

Dim String1 As String
Dim String2 As String
Dim String3 As String
Dim String4 As String

String1 = "=""Et la Société "
String2 = """&'Proposition de contrat'!C6&"""
String3 = " domiciliée "
String4 = """&RECHERCHEV(C17;'Liste des sous-traitants'!A2:F35;2;VRAI)&"""""

Worksheets("Commande de Travaux").Range("A30").Value = String1 & String2 & String3 & String4

End Sub
```

Cans someone explains to me why I receive this error ? (the formula is in French, but I don't think it's a problem because even when I only enter string 1 it doesn't function)

Comment: Looks as if you want to write a formula, not a string. If you want to write a formula, use `.formula`, not `.value`. However, it looks as if you want to write your formula in French. Either translate the formula into english (and use comma instead of semicolon as parameter separator), or use `.formulaLocal` (but then your code breaks if you or someone else uses Excel with a different language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String 1 won't work by itself because it lacks the closing quote.

When I make a new workbook and create sheets with the following names:

- Proposition de contrat
- Liste des sous-traitants
- Commande de Travaux

and change string 4 to English as follows:

```
String4 = """&vlookup(C17,'Liste des sous-traitants'!A2:F35,2,true)&"""""
```

Your code works fine for me.  At first, I thought that your issue might have been that one of the sheet names did not match, but that would be error #9, not #1004.  Here is my complete that functions in case it is of help.

```
Sub ConcatenateS()

    Dim String1 As String
    Dim String2 As String
    Dim String3 As String
    Dim String4 As String
    
    String1 = "=""Et la Société "
    String2 = """&'Proposition de contrat'!C6&"""
    String3 = " domiciliée "
    String4 = """&vlookup(C17,'Liste des sous-traitants'!A2:F35,2,true)&"""""
    
    Debug.Print String1 & String2 & String3 & String4
    Worksheets("Commande de Travaux").Range("A30").value = String1 & String2 & String3 & String4

End Sub
```